# Some trouble with a wordpress directory I've added to an old site

Tags: wordpress

I have fixed many 404 pages on the site, and added a few blogs with deep links, and some good authoritative backlinks, but it is still not ranking. Tried submitting to webmaster, added some fundamental SEO apps, but worried this is going to take a year to come back to life because of the 404s that I had. Any ideas on what could be the problem. I have tried literally everything, the URLs are canonical, etc.. still issue... I use to have  really high ranking bog, but I hosted it on a different site, and forwarded my blog links to this other site, then I thought traffic would be higher if I matched everything over to the same site, but appears this was more of an issue,

Comment: So just to clarify I have deleted the post that I accidentally duplicated, but there was no answer to the question, it was just saying that it was in the wrong discussion... the discussion triggered WordPress searches because of how it was phrased for WordPress jobs, but not exactly pertaining to WordPress developmental issues in a job-related section on the StackExchange site, but I deleted that question and earned the peer pressure badge... No one has actually answered my question except the system saying that it was in the wrong place.

Comment: An elaboration on this question could be how can I index/toggle multiple site maps because the one for my core site from hosting is still very important. The WordPress site is supposed to be a microsite, and none of the questions that are related to the thread I opened is actually related to my question, I already deleted 404 pages or masked them with forwarding URLs to appropriate content and those are not WordPress pages